# GluonMobile Css Navigation Drawer selected

Tags: css, gluon-mobile

On GluonMobile is there a way to have the CSS when a Item is selected in the drawer?

My application will have a lot of menu so I want to be able to see rapidly on wish one we are.

I manage to get the Item color, the Hover color but not the selected.

```
.navigation-drawer{

   -fx-background-color: -primary-swatch-500;
}


.item  {
   -fx-background-color: -primary-swatch-300;
}

.item > .item-content:hover{
   -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

I try all these thing

```
.item:selected
.item > .item-content:selected
.item:focused
.item > .item-content:focused
```

But nothing work.

So first can someone explain me why I need to do
.item > .item-content:hover and why not just .item:hover like in any other CSS ive done before.

Second I find it really hard to work with GluonMobile do to the lack of documentation IMO.

Maybee I dnt find the write documentation yet but the fact that I needed to do a printLn to find the styleSheet of a Node for me I find it weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaDoc for Gluon Mobile controls, like the `NavigationDrawer.Item` is [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/NavigationDrawer.Item.html).

However, you won't find the style classes applied to these controls, as you won't find it either in the JavaFX built-in controls javadoc.

Whenever you have issues with finding out the right style classes and pseudoclasses I'd strongly suggest you use [ScenicView](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view).

Find the [distribution](https://jgilesoss.blob.core.windows.net/scenic-view/scenic-view-8.7.0.zip) for Java 8, and run it:

```
java -jar scenicView.jar
```

while you also run your Gluon Mobile project on desktop:

```
./gradlew run
```

For instance, when you open the drawer of a default Glisten-Afterburner template project, you can see:

[image: SV+GM]

The node with `item` style class is a `ViewItem`, and it gets the `selected` and `hover` states.

The node with `item-content` is an `HBox`, child of `ViewItem`, and while it gets `hover`, it doesn't get `selected`:

[image: Item-content]

Following the hierarchy of nodes you can also create the hierarchy of style classes, like:

```
.navigation-drawer > * > .scroll-pane > .viewport > * > .container > .item > .item-container
```

So for each item in the drawer, the different states can be:

```
.item:hover {}
.item:selected {}
.item:selected:hover {}
```

or for the content node:

```
.item:selected > .item-content {}
.item:selected:hover > .item-content {}
...
```

In your case, you could just apply something like:

```
.item {
    -fx-background-color: -primary-swatch-300;
}

.item > .item-content:hover {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.item:selected > .item-content { 
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.item:selected:hover > .item-content {
    -fx-background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

to get something like:

[image]

Comment: That's a really good program. It will help a lot.
Thanks. It work perfectly